# How to set Zoom control limits for a div tag using JS or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a div tag and I need to set the limit for max zoom and min zoom how to do that in Jquery or JS ?

I need css Zoom property not Google APIs

actually now its zooming in and out without limits.

div.maxzoom ?
div.minZoom ?

Comment: Are you referring to the css zoom property?

Comment: @MichaelArrison Yes man

Comment: This is not a code dump site! What steps have you taken to do what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check max and min zoom value.
For example, `zoomP` will be click button. After that increase zoom value. If the zoom value will be maxZoom, the zoom value is not increased.

https://jsfiddle.net/7tzhq8zh/

HTML:

```
<button id="zoomP">Zoom++</button>
<button id="zoomN">Zoom--</button>

<div id="zoomDiv">
  zoom: <span id="zoomVal">1</span>
</div>
```

jS:

```
$(function(){
  var minZoom = 1;
  var maxZoom = 5;
  var $zoomP = $('#zoomP');
  var $zoomM = $('#zoomN');
  var $zoomDiv = $('#zoomDiv');
  var $zoomVal = $('#zoomVal');
  $zoomP.on('click', function(e){
      zoom(1);
  });
  $zoomM.on('click', function(e){
      zoom(-1);
  });
  function zoom(num) {
    var zoomVal = parseInt($zoomDiv.css('zoom'), 10);
    zoomVal = zoomVal + num;
    // check limits
    if (zoomVal < minZoom || zoomVal > maxZoom) {
        return;
    }
    $zoomDiv.css('zoom', zoomVal);
    $zoomVal.html(zoomVal);
  }
});
```